# Error invoking LLVM CodeGen pass using clang: Trying to construct TargetPassConfig without a target machine

Tags: llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-codegen

I have been trying to invoke my out-of-tree LLVM Function pass using clang (opt is not an option. Works fine with opt btw):

> clang -std=c99 -m64 -c -o file.o -DSPEC -DNDEBUG  -Ispec_qsort
>   -DSPEC_AUTO_SUPPRESS_OPENMP -g -march=native  -fno-unsafe-math-optimizations -Xclang -load -Xclang path/to/MyPass.so
>   path/to/my_lib.a
>   -fno-strict-aliasing -fgnu89-inline -DSPEC_LP64  file.c

But I get the following error:

```
error in backend: Trying to construct TargetPassConfig without a target machine. Scheduling a CodeGen pass without a target triple set?
```

The pass works fine if I remove the code related to TargetPassConfig.

I register the pass with clang by doing the following:

```
static void registerClangPass ( const PassManagerBuilder &,
legacy :: PassManagerBase & PM )
{ PM . add ( new MyPass ()); }

static RegisterStandardPasses RegisterClangPass
( PassManagerBuilder :: EP_ModuleOptimizerEarly  , registerClangPass );
static RegisterStandardPasses RegisterClangPass0
( PassManagerBuilder :: EP_EnabledOnOptLevel0  , registerClangPass );
```

To get a rough idea how my pass looks like, please take a look at:

> https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/lib/CodeGen/SafeStack.cpp

which also has dependency on TargetPassConfig. The following line seems to be the problem:
`TM = &getAnalysis<TargetPassConfig>().getTM<TargetMachine>();`

I am not sure how I can invoke/populate TargetMachine before my pass runs. But as mentioned above, the pass works fine with opt. Therefore, I am reluctant to change the pass logic.

Any pointers would be appreciated.